# metapost macro for drawing filled circle not working

Tags: metapost

The following macro draws a black circle only on the first invocation. The remaining three circles are unfilled. Where am I going wrong?

```
def big(expr z) = 
begingroup
save a;
path a;
a = fullcircle scaled 3mm;
fill a withcolor black;
draw a shifted z;
endgroup
enddef;

beginfig(1)

big(origin); %black circle drawn
big((1cm,0)); % unfilled circle
big((2.5cm,0)); % unfilled circle
big((3cm,0)); % unfilled circle

endfig;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first command

```
fill a withcolor black;
```

draws a filled circle centered at origin. The second command

```
draw a shifted z;
```

draws the circles shifted by `z`. What you want is to also shift the filled circle:

```
fill a shifted z withcolor black;
draw a shifted z;
```

or, more simply:

```
def big(expr z) = 
    begingroup
    save a; path a;
    a = fullcircle shifted z scaled 3mm;
    fill a withcolor black;
    draw a;
    endgroup
enddef;
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. But then why did this work for the first circle?

Comment: @suresh Because the first circle has its center in the origin; your code fills each time *that* circle.

Comment: @suresh: because the first circle is not being shifted at all (`origin` == `(0,0)`).